# Using TOP in a simple SQL string (VB6)

Tags: sql, adodb, jet

I'm sure there is a really simple solution for this matter, but I have tried all I know without success.

I'm trying to modify this fully Working SQL string to yield only the Top 25 results, not all results. Spaces corrected on this post. (I have used the TOP 25, etc. with Jet/Access databases for years with no problems)

```
"SELECT * FROM " & "data.CSV" & " ORDER BY " & "Elapsed" & " DESC "*
```

For the Top 25 SQL syntax I have tested:

```
1."SELECT TOP 25 FROM " & "data.CSV" & " ORDER BY " & "Elapsed" & " DESC "
2."SELECT TOP 25 * FROM " & "data.CSV" & "ORDER BY " & "ELAPSED" & " DESC "
3."SELECT TOP 25" & " ORDER BY " & "ELAPSED" & " DESC " & FROM" & " data.CSV"
```

None of these three produce any results from the 45 line test data file. No errors indicated, all compile.

Edit: Corrected spaces of working string. Actual code in use is correct. Corrected missing double quote line 2.

Any advice appreciated.

Edit: Code added.

```
Private Sub Command4_Click() '*** Print direct to report ***
Dim Cn1 As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim strData, iSQLStr As String
Dim sData() As String
Dim c, i, s As Integer

 On Error Resume Next

  Set Cn1 = New ADODB.Connection
  Cn1.ConnectionString = _
    "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & _
    "DefaultDir=" & "C:\"  
  Cn1.Open

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Fields.Append "Room", adVarChar, 2
rs.Fields.Append "Procedure", adVarChar, 2
rs.Fields.Append "Group", adVarChar, 12
rs.Fields.Append "Label", adVarChar, 12
rs.Fields.Append "Time_In", adVarChar, 22
rs.Fields.Append "Time_Out", adVarChar, 22
rs.Fields.Append "Elapsed", adVarChar, 8
rs.Open

'iSQLStr = "Select TOP 25" & " ORDER BY " & "Elapsed" & " DESC " & "FROM"   & " data.csv"
'iSQLStr = "Select TOP 25 * FROM" & " data.csv" & " ORDER BY " &  "Elapsed" & " DESC "
iSQLStr = "Select * FROM " & "data.csv" & " ORDER BY " & "Elapsed" & " DESC "
Set rs = Cn1.Execute(iSQLStr)

Set DataReport1.DataSource = rs
DataReport1.Show vbModal
rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: your first one will **NOT** compile. you have no spaces between the strings, so you're building `SELECT ... FROMdata.CSVORDER BYElapsed Desc`, which is an outright syntax error. And are you trying to select from a .csv file, or are you in a database named `data`, with  table named `CSV`?

Comment: Your second one should work given the additional spaces as mentioned by @MarcB.  Also, it's missing a double quote a the end... 
`"SELECT TOP 25 * FROM" & " data.CSV" & " ORDER BY " & "ELAPSED" & " DESC "`

Comment: Your second statement doesn't select any rows, so it will fail. Your third statement doesn't leave a space between the file name and the `ORDER BY` and the `DESC` is not encapsulated in double quotes. Your 4th statement has an `ORDER BY` before the `FROM` clause which is not allowed in any RDBMS. This is a mess.

Comment: What database system is this? The correct syntax may differ.

Comment: I'm using a .CSV file not a database.  I am creating a recordset using ADODB to use data from a CVS file type.

Comment: @Ashton Please post your *actual* code.  We can't help you by guessing at what your actual problem might be, and you still have issues with your SQL Strings provided (@JNevill mentioned it earlier with the `ORDER BY` before the `FROM`)

Comment: If it's ADODB and a CSV then this is either JET or ACE db (depending on the version of Office/Windows, I can never keep that part straight). At any rate, as suggested by @jradich1234, your second attempt at a `TOP 25` is the correct one, just fix the formatting. Essentially, copy verbatim what you have in your working example and add `TOP 25` to it. Don't change anything else, and you will be golden.

Comment: @Ashton Out of curiosity, why are you even messing with string concatenation?  Why not just do `iSQLStr = "SELECT TOP 25 * FROM data.csv ORDER BY Elapsed DESC"`

Comment: Wow. this is working, except Its not pulling accurate quantities.

Comment: Strange. this is working, except Its not pulling accurate quantities.
    iSQLStr = "Select TOP 20 * FROM" & " data.csv" & " ORDER BY " & "Elapsed" & " DESC "

I have never seen anything like this.
Using 10 nets 12 records, 20 nets 20, 25 nets 32, 30 nets 32.

I can loose the concatenation.  I had just not removed the quotes from other code snips from long segmented SQL string from a DB project.

Comment: Solved.
  I randomized my test data Elapsed ORDER BY values (ie. 00:12:54) and now netting the correct quantity.  (?) Maybe spaces at end of CSV?
TOP 25 returns 25 now.  No concatenation. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"SELECT TOP 25 * FROM " & "data.CSV" & "ORDER BY " & "ELAPSED" & DESC "
```

Is the one that looks closest to working except it's missing some spaces.

What language is this in? I don't know what the ampersands and quotes are all meaning, but if you can build the string like this it should work:

```
SELECT TOP 25 * FROM data.CSV ORDER BY ELAPSED DESC
```

Following the syntax you're using I think this has the correct spacing:

```
"SELECT TOP 25 * FROM " & "data.CSV " & "ORDER BY " & "ELAPSED " & DESC"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the column(s) you want to select.

```
SELECT TOP number|percent column_name(s)
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score -3):

Just add the `LIMIT` option at the end of your query. If it is sorted or ordered the way you want it then just add `LIMIT` 25 to the end and It will return the first 25 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM" & "data.CSV" & "ORDER BY " & "Elapsed" & " DESC **LIMIT 25**
```

Comment: `LIMIT` is RDBMS specific. It works in Mysql, Oracle, and Postgres. It does not work in Sql Server, Jet/Ace/Access, Teradata, for instance.